# How Regin hides running instances of itself?

Tags: malware, rootkits

I have been reading Symantec & Kaspersky Labs analysis of the Regin malware.

According to Symantec

> [Stage 2] can also hide running instances of Stage 1. Once this
>   happens, there are no remaining plainly visible code artifacts.

As I understand Stage 1 is implemented as a Windows Driver, and there exists no safe way to unload a Windows Driver without requiring a reboot (Even if so Stage 2 itself is another kernel driver as well).

Similarly, from what I can tell there exists no way (nor legitimately should there be) to intercept and manipulate the list of running Kernel drivers, the way a rootkit might for a file on the file system.

So how does Stage 2 hide running instances of Stage 1? There seems little information on this online?

Source: 
http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/regin-analysis.pdf - Page 9

Comment: As a driver you can manipulate the internal kernel data structures to remove some driver from the lists. I don't have much kernel hacking experience, but I know that several game hacks used the userland equivalent of this technique to remove their dll from the list of loaded dlls.

Comment: It might be difficult to provide a definite answer without looking at the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a kernel hacker, but from what I read the technique is analogous to a function hook in user space.

### Premise

- User space code interacts with the kernel through system calls.
- There are system calls that reveal information about the state of the kernel, e. g. *f* returns list of loaded kernel modules.
- The kernel manages a table *t* of system calls and the location of their implementation in memory.
- A kernel module (a. k. a. “driver”) *m* becomes a part of the kernel, when it's loaded, thus gaining full access to everything the kernel can access.

### Steps

1. *m* is loaded/injected into the kernel in some way. Now it can do anything it wants to the OS including hooking into some of its infrastructure.
2. *m* replaces entry *t<sub>f</sub>* holding a reference to function *f*, which would help to reveal the presence of *m*. In its stead *m* places a reference to a similar function *f'* into *t<sub>f</sub>*, which is a part of *m* and uses *f* but filters and/or transforms the results as to hide the traces of *m*.
3. A user space program is looking for suspicious kernel modules and wants to call *f*. After receiving the system call the kernel looks up *t<sub>f</sub>*, because it expects *t<sub>f</sub>* to hold a reference to *f*. Instead it finds and calls *f'*. Thus the user space program will receive a result controlled by *m*.